# When changing fillStyle of path on canvas color actually blends not changes

Tags: javascript, canvas, alphablending

I'm trying to change fillStyle of an path to fully transparent, but instead I get blended colors.

```
/*****************************
ALL BELOW JUST SIMULATING CASE
*****************************/
var c1 = document.getElementById("cool");
var ctx = c1.getContext("2d")

var elem=[0,0,50,0,100,0];
var elem2=[50,0,50,50,50,100];

var i=1;

var path = new Path2D();
path.moveTo(elem[i+1], elem[i+2]);
path.lineTo(elem2[i+1], elem2[i+2]);
path.lineTo(elem2[i-1], elem2[i]);
path.lineTo(elem[i+1], elem[i+2]);
path.closePath();

ctx.fillStyle = getRndColor();
ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle;
ctx.fill(path);
ctx.stroke(path);

//this function shouldn't have impact on problem, but i put it here just in case
var getRndColor = function () {
    var r = 255*Math.random()|0,
        g = 255*Math.random()|0,
        b = 255*Math.random()|0;
    return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
}

/*****************************
ALL ABOVE JUST SIMULATING CASE
*****************************/

var changeElement = function(path) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle;
    ctx.fill(path);
    ctx.stroke(path);
    console.log(ctx.fillStyle);
}

changeElement(path); //if you try e.g. 50% opacity, you will see that color blends
```

How to change path fillStyle? Is it possible to clear not rectangle area of canvas?

Comment: There are ways to clear an non rectangular area of your context ([`globlaCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) or `getImageData`+`putImageData` can achieve this), but in your case (partially transparent strokes), you'll get only ugly results (gCO won't work and you'll get anti-aliasing crap with `putImageData`method). So depending on your real use case, the best is either to redraw everything, or to keep a copy of your context in a buffer canvas before drawing the path, then use `drawImage` to revert this state.

Comment: As I expect I have to rebuild my conception. I was going to try redrawing but didn't consider using additional canvas, thanks for this idea :)

Comment: Man, globalCompositeOperation solved problem completely - do your wan't to post you answer? I can honor you and if someone in the future will have same problem, he can find solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey, so here comes simple solution. Big thanks to [Kalido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido).

In my case I could just change `globalCompositeOperation` value to `source-in` and then I could change the color (and opacity) instead of blending colors.

Note that you changing this value to whole context so I found quite good practice to set it back to default value after you use it.

My code example:

```
var changeElement = function(path) {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle;
    ctx.fill(path);
    ctx.stroke(path);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; //setting back to default value to prevent odd behavior of other part of canvas.
}

changeElement(path);
```